# how to limit the number of concurrent map tasks per executor?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

A map operation in my Spark APP takes an `RDD[A]` as input and map each element in `RDD[A]` using a custom mapping function `func(x:A):B` to another object of type B. Because `func()` requires significant amount of memory when computing each input `x`, I want to limit the number of concurrent map tasks per executor such that the total amount of memory required by all tasks on the same executor does not exceeds the amount of physical memory available on the node.

I checked out available spark configurations, but not sure which one to use. Does using `coalesce(numPartitions)` to set the number of partitions for `RDD[A]` fulfil the purpose?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? We are also stuck at the same situation.

Answer (score 8):

The number of concurrent tasks per executor is related to the available number of cores, not the number of tasks, so changing the parallelism level using `coalesce` or `repartition` will not help in constraining the used memory for each task, only the amount of data on each partition that needs to be processed by a given task (*).

As far as I know, there's no way to constrain the memory used by a single task, because it's sharing the resources of the worker JVM, and hence sharing memory with the other tasks on the same executor.

Assuming a fair share per task, a guideline for the amount of memory available per task (core) will be:

```
spark.executor.memory * spark.storage.memoryFraction / #cores-per-executor
```

Probably, a way to force less tasks per executor, and hence more memory available per task, would be to assign more cores per task, using `spark.task.cpus` (default = 1)

(*) Given that the concern here is at the level of each element `x` of an RDD, the only possible setting that could affect memory usage is to set a parallelism level less than the number of CPUs of a single executor, but that would result in severe under-utilization of the cluster resources as all workers but one will be idle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I will have a try. However, change `spark.task.cpus` will take effect on all the tasks. What should I do if I want to change its value for ONE particular `map()` operation?

Comment: It seems to me that setting `spark.task.cpus` to number > 1 will take effect globally. Meanwhile, I think `coalesce` would be a better option if we first call `RDD.coalesce(#_of_nodes)` to make sure each node gets one partition of the RDD then call `RDD.repartition()` to increase level of parallelism after the memory consuming `map()` operation.

Comment: There's no warranty that doing `coalesce(#of_nodes)` will ensure 1 task/node unless you only have 1 cpu/node. Imagine you have 4 nodes, each with 4 CPUs. When you do `rdd.coalesce(4)`, one node has sufficient capacity (CPUs) to process all partitions of your RDD. That will also leave all the other 3 nodes idle. Not what you want, I guess.  `spark.task.cpus` is also a hack and will impact the complete job; I agree.

Comment: @maasg how to set spark.task.cpus property in spark??